# Android CalendarView inconsistent

Tags: android, calendarview

I am displaying a CalendarView in one of my ViewPager Fragments. In the emulator in Android Studio, the CalendarView is showing correctly as in the screenshot top.

When I run the app in an actual device, it is showing the CalendarView differently as in the screenshot bottom.

In the emulator, I can scroll to the next and previous months properly using the arrow keys. But on the actual device, I can't.

How do I make the CalendarView consistently show and behave in both device and emulator? Do I need to use a third-party calendar library? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Its depend on your android version, does your real device version is greater or equal with your emulator version?

Comment: No, the emulator version is greater than the device version.

Comment: Yes exactly its depends on Android version because your emulator using latest Android version that's why you get this type of calendar and your real device version is lower.

Comment: Ok, but at least it should scroll months on the real device, right? Also, what should I do if I want the top calendar format for real devices also? Do I need to write a custom calendar?

Comment: You should go with this lib https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers i hope it will helps you :)

Comment: Ok, thanks. :) That's what I was not sure of (using a third-party calendar).